# How to pack a variable into an HTTP GET request in socket.send() - Python 2.7

Tags: sockets, http, get, user-input

First off thanks for reading!

Second off YES I have tried to find the answer! :) Perhaps I haven't found it because I'm not using the right words to describe my problem, but it's been about 4 hours that I've been trying to figure it out now and I'm getting a little loopy trying to piece it together on my own.

I am very new to programming. Python is my first language. I am on my third Python course. I have an assignment to use the socket library (not urllib library - I know how to do that) to make a socket and use GET to receive information. The problem is that the program needs to take raw input for the URL in question.

I have everything else the way I want it, but I need to know the syntax that I'm supposed to be using INSIDE my "GET" request in order for the HTTP message to include the requested document path.

I have tried (obviously not all together lol):

```
mysock.send('GET (url) HTTP/1.0\n\n')
mysock.send( ('GET (url) HTTP:/1.0\n\n'))
mysock.send(('GET (url) HTTP:/1.0\n\n'))
mysock.send("GET (url) HTTP/1.0\n\n")
mysock.send( ("'GET' (url) HTTP:/1.0\n\n"))
mysock.send(("'GET' (url) 'HTTP:/1.0\n\n'"))
```

and:

basically every other configuration of the above (, ((, ( (, ', '' combinations listed above.

I have also tried:

-Creating a string using the 'url' variable first, and then including it inside mysock.send(string)
-Again with the "string-first" theory, but this time I used %r to refer to my user input (so 'GET %r HTTP/1.0\n\n' % url basically)

I've read questions here, other programming websites, the whole chapter in the book and the whole lectures/notes online, I've read articles on the socket library and the .send(), and of course articles on GET requests... but I'm clearly missing something. It seems most don't use socket library when they can use urllib and I don't blame them!!

Thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the university posted back to me that the url variable can concatenated with the GET syntax and assigned to a string variable which can then be called with .send(concatenatedvariable) - I had mentioned trying that but had missed that GET requires a space after the word 'GET' so of course concatenating didn't include a space and that blew it. In case anyone else wants to know :)

Answer (score 0):

FYI: A fully quallified URL is only allowed in HTTP/1.1 requests. It is not the norm, though, as HTTP/1.1 requires setting the `Host` header. The relevant piece of reading would've been [RFC 7230, sec. 3.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) and possibly [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). The syntax of the parameters is largely borrowed from the CGI format. It is in no way enforced, however. In a nutshell, everything put together would look like this on the wire:

```
GET /path?param1=value1&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

As a final note: The line delimiter in HTTP is CRLF (`\r\n`). For robustness, a simple linefeed is acceptable as well but not recommended.